# Dealing with conditional heteroskedasticity in dynamic linear model

Tags: time-series, arima, heteroscedasticity, dynamic-regression

I'm working on a regression problem and am struggling to figure out how to deal with the conditional heteroskedasticity present in the error terms. I will try and work through what I have done so far, but the end question is :

**How do I produce valid confidence intervals from a dynamic linear regression where the model errors display conditional heteroskedasticity?**

The crux of the problem is that I am trying to estimate a beta coefficient between 2 different variables. Some important points:

1. Interpretation of the beta in original units is extremely important, so I want to try and avoid complicated transformations of the data where possible.
2. I eventually want to obtain valid confidence intervals on the regression parameters.

**Visualising the data**:
[image: We have 2 clearly non-stationary time series]

We have 2, very clearly non-stationary time series (X, the independent variable, and Y, the dependant variable).

Taking differences and applying the adf.test to check for stationarity before any modelling :

[image]

ADF Test results :

```
data:  data.diff[, 1]
Dickey-Fuller = -14.518, Lag order = 14, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

data:  data.diff[, 2]
Dickey-Fuller = -14.603, Lag order = 14, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Using the differenced time series, I use the *auto.arima* function in R to fit an ARIMA model :

```
ARMAReg = forecast::auto.arima(y = data.diff[,1],xreg = data.diff[,2])
summary(ARMAReg)

Series: data.diff[, 1] 
Regression with ARIMA(3,0,2) errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3      ma1     ma2        X
      0.3297  -0.9302  -0.0773  -0.3913  0.9462  -0.0510
s.e.  0.0393   0.0217   0.0191   0.0353  0.0213   0.0009

sigma^2 = 4.034:  log likelihood = -6394.72
AIC=12803.44   AICc=12803.48   BIC=12845.54

Training set error measures:
                       ME     RMSE      MAE MPE MAPE     MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.0007491417 2.006506 1.338148 NaN  Inf 0.514481 0.001929202
```

When we look at the residuals in this model, they seem ok on first glance :

[image]

Theres some random spikes in the residuals every 6 months or so, but this is due to a known issue with the X value data (which I will fix).

However, when we look at the pacf of the square residuals, we see clear signs of heteroskedasticity :

[image]

Now given the knowledge I have of these 2 time series, I know the relationship between them is dynamic, so I tried to fit a dynamic linear regression model with time vary coefficients, with a plot of the time varying beta and its 2sd confidence intervals below (most of the code was taken from here : http://lalas.github.io/quantitativeThoughts/) :

```
start.vals = c(0,0,0)

buildDLM = function(parm, x.mat){
    parm = exp(parm)
  return( dlmModReg(X=x.mat, dV=parm[1], dW=c(parm[2], parm[3])) )
}

DLM.mle = dlmMLE(y=data.diff[,1], parm=start.vals, x.mat=data.diff[,2], build=buildDLM, hessian=T)

DLM.dlm = buildDLM(DLM.mle$par, data.diff[,2])

DLM.filtered = dlmFilter(y = data.diff[,1], mod = DLM.dlm)

alpha.f = xts(DLM.filtered$m[-1,1,drop=FALSE],order.by = index(data.diff))
beta.f  = xts(DLM.filtered$m[-1,2,drop=FALSE],order.by = index(data.diff))

mse.list = dlmSvd2var(DLM.filtered$U.C, DLM.filtered$D.C)
se.mat = t(sapply(mse.list, FUN=function(x) sqrt(diag(x))))
se.xts = xts(se.mat[-1, ], index(beta.f))
colnames(se.xts) = c("alpha", "beta")
a.u = alpha.f + 1.96*se.xts[, "alpha"]
a.l = alpha.f - 1.96*se.xts[, "alpha"]
b.u = beta.f  + 1.96*se.xts[, "beta"]
b.l = beta.f  - 1.96*se.xts[, "beta"]

PerformanceAnalytics::chart.TimeSeries(cbind(beta.f, b.l, b.u)[-c(1:20)], main="Filtered estimates of beta",
                 colorset=c(1,2,2), lty=c(1,3,3),ylab=expression(beta),xlab="")
```

[image]

Now we get to the heart of my problem (and thank you for reading this far!). If i look at the residuals from this model, theres a couple of issues. The first is there is clearly some autocorrelation here, but this I know can be solved by fitting a DLM ARMA model (which I done but wont add here as the post is already quite long) :

[image]

The main problem I am trying to solve is the problem of conditional heteroskedasticity, which can be seen in :

[image]

As far as I am aware, this will render my confidence intervals on the parameter estimates useless (please correct me if I am wrong), so assuming I can fix the auto correlation with a DLM ARMA model, how would I go about fixing the heteroskedasticity so that I can produce valid confidence intervals **without applying arbitrary transformations to the data that makes interpretation of the beta impossible** ? I would also like to stick with a model that allows the beta to vary with time as I know this is how the series behave vs on another. So far my thoughts on how to solve are :

1. I know for fixed parameter regression one can produce heteroskedasticity robust standard errors - is this possible to do with a state space regression ?
2. I have read a lot about GARCH and Stochastic Volatility models to deal with this issue, but they dont really strike me as regression models, so I'm not sure if these would work.
3. I have no idea if this would make any sense but I have read about use a Particle Filters to estimate the parameters of a state space model instead of a Kalman Filter when the error terms are non-gaussian. Is this something worth exploring ?

Thanks for reading, and any help would be much appreciated!